# Python multiprocessing problem using list comprehension

Tags: python, multiprocessing, list-comprehension, return-value

I'm having a problem understanding why multiprocessing, list comprehension inputs are not updated, specifically the 'val2chg' entry in my example code below. I wouldn't be surprised by this except it works fine without multiprocessing. The multiprocessing code is successful if passing the 'same' list without the list comprehension. I'm sure others have run into this, but I haven't been able to phrase my search terms correctly to come up with a link to the answer.

Below is a simple example, results followed by code.

```
The input (sld) is
   [{'val': 0, 'val2chg': 'not'}, {'val': 1, 'val2chg': 'not'}]
The four results are
   multiproc: True. listcomp: True, [{'val': 0, 'val2chg': 'not'}, {'val': 1, 'val2chg': 'not'}]
   multiproc: False. listcomp: True, [{'val': 0, 'val2chg': 'changed'}, {'val': 1, 'val2chg': 'changed'}]
   multiproc: False. listcomp: False, [{'val': 0, 'val2chg': 'changed'}, {'val': 1, 'val2chg': 'changed'}]
   multiproc: True. listcomp: False, [{'val': 0, 'val2chg': 'changed'}, {'val': 1, 'val2chg': 'changed'}]

import multiprocessing as mp
sld = [{'val':0, 'val2chg':'not'}, {'val':1, 'val2chg':'not'}]
print(sld)
def update_values(sld, domp):
        global update
        def update(idx, some):
                some['val2chg'] = 'changed'
                return idx, some
        if domp:
                pool = mp.Pool()
                results = [pool.apply_async(update, (idx, sld[idx])) for idx in range(len(sld))]
                pool.close()
                pool.join()
                for result in results:
                        idx = result.get()[0]
                        sld[idx] = result.get()[1]
        else:
                for idx in range(len(sld)):
                        results = update(idx, sld[idx])
                        idx = results[0]
                        sld[idx] = results[1]
domp = True
listcomp = False
if listcomp:
        update_values([s for idx, s in enumerate(sld)], domp)
else:
        update_values(sld, domp)
print(f'multiproc: {domp}. listcomp: {listcomp}, {sld}')
```

Comment: Mention your os in the question

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain this the best way I can:

First of all your statement:

```python
if listcomp:
        update_values([s for idx, s in enumerate(sld)], domp)
```

can be simplified to:

```python
if listcomp:
        update_values([s for s in sld)], domp)
```

which is equivalent to:

```python
if listcomp:
        arg = [s for s in sld)]
        update_values(arg, domp)
```

But what you are now doing is passing to `update_values` a list `arg` that is a shallow copy of list `sld` rather than `sld` itself where `arg[0] == sld[0]`, i.e. each list references the same dictionary elements.

In the non-multiprocessing case when `update` is called you are passing a reference to each element of `arg` or `sld` depending on the value of `domp`. But in either case they are the same dictionary references contained in `sld`. The code `some['val2chg'] = 'changed'` in `update` is therefore actually **updating in place the dictionaries referenced by `sld`** (which, again, are same dictionaries referenced by `arg`). So even when `listcomp` is true and the return values from `update` are being used to update the past `arg` list instead of the `sld` list, it doesn't matter because the dictionary elements refrenced by `sld` were already updated by `update`.

However, in the multiprocessing case, what is being passed to `update` is now a serialized/de-serialized **copy** of the dictionary references. The statement `some['val2chg'] = 'changed'` is modifying that copy, which lives in the address space of the pool process that is executing this statement. So we now must rely on `update_values` using the return value from `update` to update the passed `sld` argument, which, unfortunately, is not the global `sld` list but rather its copy, `arg`.

The following is updated code, which unlike yours that only works for platforms that by default create new processes using the *fork* method (e.g. Linux), should work for all platforms. I have also modified the spacing to conform with PEP8 guidelines:

```python
import multiprocessing as mp

def update(idx, some):
    some['val2chg'] = 'changed'
    return idx, some

def update_values(sld, domp):
    if domp:
        pool = mp.Pool()
        results = [pool.apply_async(update, (idx, sld[idx])) for idx in range(len(sld))]
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        for result in results:
            idx, some = result.get()
            sld[idx] = some
    else:
        for idx in range(len(sld)):
            results = update(idx, sld[idx])
            idx = results[0]
            sld[idx] = results[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    domp = True
    listcomp = True

    sld = [{'val':0, 'val2chg':'not'}, {'val':1, 'val2chg':'not'}]
    print(sld)

    if listcomp:
        #arg = [s for idx, s in enumerate(sld)]
        # The above can be simplified to:
        arg = [s for s in sld]
        # But now arg is a copy of sld and it is the copy that is being modified
        update_values(arg, domp)
        # We now need this (but we really shouldn't be using a list comprehension at all):
        sld = arg
    else:
        update_values(sld, domp)
    print(f'multiproc: {domp}. listcomp: {listcomp}, {sld}')
```

Prints:

```
[{'val': 0, 'val2chg': 'not'}, {'val': 1, 'val2chg': 'not'}]
multiproc: True. listcomp: True, [{'val': 0, 'val2chg': 'changed'}, {'val': 1, 'val2chg': 'changed'}]
```